# Delphi RESTClient POST request

Tags: rest, delphi, delphi-xe6

Well, I'm developing a REST Client application that needs to send a POST request using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as Content type. I'm using Delphi's default [REST.Client](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/REST.Client) components. I need to send data in XML format, like the following example:

```
    data=<serviceLocal>
    <description>Francisco Hansen</description>
    <active>true</active>
    <corporateName>Francisco Hansen</corporateName>
    <country>Brasil</country>
    <state>PR</state>
    <city>Pato Branco</city>
    <cityNeighborhood>Centro</cityNeighborhood>
    <streetType>Rua</streetType>
    <street>Tocantins</street>
    <streetNumber>2334</streetNumber>
    <streetComplement>Ap101</streetComplement>
    <zipCode>85501-272</zipCode>
    <cellphoneStd>46</cellphoneStd>
    <cellphoneNumber>99999999</cellphoneNumber>
    <phoneStd>46</phoneStd>
    <phoneNumber>99999999</phoneNumber>
    </serviceLocal>
```

How can I add all these as POST parameters to a TRestRequest and then send this request using a TRestClient?

Comment: Is that exactly real XML data? Is there really supposed to be `data=` at the beginning?

Comment: I expect so, @Jerry. The x-www-form-urlencoded format means the request's payload is ampersand-separated "key=value" pairs. In this case, the key is `data` and the value is that XML string. (It's not properly *escaped* yet, but I assume that's part of Francisco's problem.)

Comment: I see, yes it needs to be URL encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [Rest.Client.TRESTRequest](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequest) component, I've been able to set the POST parameters for the request. I've named the TRESTRequest as `rqst1`

.

```
rqst1.Method := rmPost;

rqst1.Params.AddItem; //Adds a new Parameter Item
rqst1.Params.Items[0].name := 'data'; //sets the name of the parameter. In this case, since i need to use 'data=' on the request, the parameter name is data.
rqst1.Params.Items[0].Value := params; //Adds the value of the parameter, in this case, the XML data.
rqst1.Params.Items[0].ContentType := ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED; //sets the content type.
rqst1.Params.Items[0].Kind := pkGETorPOST; //sets the kind of request that will be executed.
```